# Stopping one Dynamic when another is being changed

Tags: dynamic

In the minimum working example below I make a function in the top graph and then by pressing the button I use it in a calculation (much, much simpler than my actual calculation) and then plot the result in the bottom graph. The bottom graph also contains the function made in the top graph.

```
DynamicModule[{pts, f, g},
 pts = Table[{x, 1}, {x, 0, 3 π, π/2.}];
 f = Interpolation[pts];
 Column[{
   LocatorPane[
    Dynamic[pts,
     (
       pts = #;
       pts[[1, 1]] = 0;
       pts[[-1, 1]] = 3 π;
       f = Interpolation[pts]
       ) &
     ],
    Dynamic@Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 3 π}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 2}}]
    ],
   Button["Calculate", g[x_] := Evaluate[f[x]^2], ImageSize -> 1 72],
   Dynamic[Plot[g[x] + f[x], {x, 0, 3 π}]]
   }]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The problem is that the bottom graph changes when I change the top graph. I only want it to change after I have pressed the button. How do I do that?

I made one try by using the second argument to dynamic. If the second argument to dynamic is None then the dynamic should stop being interactive. The modified code is as follows

```
DynamicModule[{pts, f, g, action = None},
 pts = Table[{x, 1}, {x, 0, 3 π, π/2.}];
 f = Interpolation[pts];
 Column[{
   LocatorPane[
    Dynamic[pts,
     (
       pts = #;
       pts[[1, 1]] = 0;
       pts[[-1, 1]] = 3 π;
       f = Interpolation[pts];
       action = None
       ) &
     ],
    Dynamic@Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 3 π}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 2}}]
    ],
   Button["Calculate", g[x_] := Evaluate[f[x]^2]; action = Automatic, 
    ImageSize -> 1 72],
   Dynamic[Plot[g[x] + f[x], {x, 0, 3 π}], action]
   }]
 ]
```

However this does not work. Why?
Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to change the original code. You have to add `TrackedSymbols :> {g}` to your second [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html)

```
DynamicModule[{pts, f, g}, 
 pts = Table[{x, 1}, {x, 0, 3 π, π/2.}];
 f = Interpolation[pts];
 Column[{LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts, (pts = #;
       pts[[1, 1]] = 0;
       pts[[-1, 1]] = 3 π;
       f = Interpolation[pts]) &], 
    Dynamic@Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 3 π}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 2}}]], 
   Button["Calculate", g[x_] := Evaluate[f[x]^2], ImageSize -> 1 72], 
   Dynamic[Plot[g[x] + f[x], {x, 0, 3 π}], 
    TrackedSymbols :> {g}]}]]
```